# VB.NET - using multiple INSERT statement in one command

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code but it doesn't work and it shows the "Characters found after SQL statement" message. How do I fix it?

```
    objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TBL_Onvan(Onvan, Notes)VALUES(@Onvan,@Notes); AND INSERT INTO TBL_OnvanRevayat(ID_Onvan, ID_Revayat)VALUES(@ID_Onvan, @ID_Revayat)"
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Onvan", txtOnvanFaray.Text)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text)

    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Onvan", intId)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Revayat",CType(BindingContext(table).Current("ID"), String))
```

Comment: Take the `AND` out it's not needed and is invalid SQL...

Comment: Which DBMS? Sql Server?